Is there a way to stop a user from typing numbers bigger than a maximum?
Currently my code has a maximum value but it is only applied when using the increase and decrease (by 1) arrows, and when they type into the box they can go as high as they want.
Here is an example of the code:
<label>Estimated credit score&nbsp;<span>*</span></label>
[number* guarantor-credit-estimated-credit-score min:0 max:850]

Is there any way to make a maximum value that refuses the user to actually type past that limit? I know I could do a 3 digit character limit, but that still allows them to go 851-999.

Rather than preventing the user from providing the input they intend by stopping the normal and expected function of typing, consider providing feedback about why the input is invalid along with a message about what the valid range is guiding them to provide valid input.
